# Difference between one finger scroll vs 2 finger scrolling on IE11 touch device

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, multi-touch

What is the difference between scrolling with one finger and two fingers on IE11.

On some elements I can scroll/pan the webpage with 1 finger and on some elements it only works with 2 fingers on a Microsoft surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that placing touch-action to none makes all panning work with 1 finger

```
body {
    touch-action: auto;
}
```

There is a lot of documentation about all the specific IE touch css related events here, 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh920761.aspx